# Spring-Data Couchbase - How to set TTL to document from property file

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to set a TTL for document, I've learned that by putting `@Document(expiry = x sec)` works. But is there a way to read the value from a property file?

Here's my dependency:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not a feature yet. If you need a flexible TTL definition, you can use the touch method after the document is saved:
https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.0.0/com/couchbase/client/java/Bucket.html#touch(java.lang.String,%20int)

Additionally, you could also use the standard save method.

Best,

Comment: can we use n1ql query in case need to update for bulk i.e. millions of document? Is yes can you please provide sample query

Answer (score 0):

You can use expiryExpression to get the value from properties. Tested in spring-data-couchbase:4.3.1

```
@Document(expiryExpression = "${document.expiry}" , expiryUnit =TimeUnit.DAYS)
```